# Hydrogen gas tube and the spectrum

Tags: experimental-physics, atomic-physics, spectroscopy, hydrogen

Generally to detect the hydrogen spectrum people uses the hydrogen gas tube as a light source.
My question is, since the gas in the tube is the hydrogen molecule $H_2$ why is the spectrum equal to the spectrum of atomic hydrogen $H$ ?

Comment: (+1) I answer your question here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/768678/313612. The electrically energized tube has both hydrogen molecules and hydrogen atoms that came from hydrogen molecules that were dissociated, i.e., broken into atoms. Some of the atoms are excited and de-excite by emitting the characteristic hydrogen atomic emission lines, e.g., the Balmer series that I show. And likewise, some excited hydrogen molecules emit light, e.g., the Fulcher alpha bands. Please consider upvoting my answer at the link since I cannot answer here because your question is closed. Thank you!